# firebase deploy --only functions overrides existing functions

Tags: function, firebase, firebase-tools, google-cloud-functions

Running `firebase deploy --only functions` deletes the existing functions before creating new ones. Is it possible to modify this behavior to `create if not exist, update if exists, no actions if functions not being deployed`?

Answer (score 232, accepted):

You can use firebase [partial deploys](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#partial_deploys)

```
$ firebase deploy --only functions:makeUppercase
```

Will only deploy `makeUppercase` function.

Note: To deploy more than one function at once (but not all) use:

```
$ firebase deploy --only functions:function1,functions:function2
```

Comment: It's also possible to deploy multiple functions in a partial deploy: `firebase deploy --only functions:function1,functions:function2`

Comment: I believe the best solution would be using groups, also seen in the documentation link.

Comment: But how should you actually NAME your firebase functions? What does it Actually look like?

Answer (score 16):

Since version 3.8 of the Firebase tools CLI this *is* possible. See Pablo's answer or the [release notes](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v3.8.0).

Prior to 3.8, running `firebase deploy` will deploy all functions in the project. There is no option to deploy just new or modified functions.

It *does* sound like a useful addition though, so you might want to [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Comment: I could use some help with this! I would like to deploy multiple functions as well. I have set up my project structure exactly like https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples has. In fact, I used it as a base, stripped all but two functions, modified, and want to deploy. I have tried firebase deploy, firebase deploy --only ..., and comma separated attempts.

Comment: If I run "firebase deploy" from root I get that it couldn't locate firebase.json.  My guess is I have to restructure the applications, but I haven't had any luck after trying a few alternatives.

Comment: @QuinnTurner Try running `firebase init`, which will add all necessary files.

Comment: @QuinnTurner please don't post new questions in a comment. If you have a new problem, post a new question. Be sure to include the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in that question (and read the link, it's quite useful).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are editing the functions in your "functions/src" directory and not the functions in your 'lib' directory.  I made this mistake and watched them get replaced...